# Set/Get keychain item without requiring a password for a specific app/binary

Tags: macos, go, command-line-interface, keychain

I want to set and get a password in MacOS Keychain Access that is only accessible by a specific golang binary without confirmation prompt.

Any other apps trying to access should require the password before being able to get the password.

It works for a specific binary. But if I build a new binary it starts requiring the password.

Already tried signing the binary with a self signed certificate but does not seem to work.

```
codesign --force --verify --verbose=4 --deep --timestamp --options=runtime \
    --sign "My Self Signed Key" \
    ssh-agent
```

Any ideas? What can I be doing wrong?